# Copy records from multiple tables in one database to another

Tags: ms-access, vba

hope someone can help
Trying to Copy data from current access database to an sql database.
Have created a connection to the SQL db and then tried to create a:
connection.execute "INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM " statement
Cannot get the FROM to take records from a table in the current db, it errors with 'Invalid object name' and quotes the source table name.
INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES(values) works ok but as I will be copying data from 30 plus different tables I would like to avoid using field names

Have tried numerous things, one of which is:
gCon.Execute "INSERT INTO AE_ParameterTest1 SELECT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=" & Application.CurrentDb.Name & ";].[ParameterTest1]

Many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest you do the import from the SQL Manager Import Wizard
instead of pushing from the Access application.
It will handle all the fieldnames etc for you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * INTO Target_DB_Name.Target_Table_Name

FROM Source_DB_Name.Source_Table_Name

Where Your_Condition